# Signature field with centred content underneath it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}
```

and want some signature lines that have

1. dotted lines; plus
2. a designation below the line

I have:

```
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
Ronaldo & Date\\[8ex]% adds space between the two sets of signatures
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
Dr. Fernando Torres \begin{center}Assistant Professor Discipline Of Computer Science School Of Engineering La Liga \end{center} \newline  & Date\\
\end{tabular}
```

The content of "Assistant Professor ..." does not left align below the signature line and I can't use a `\newline` too.

I want that content to either be

1. left aligned; or
2. centre aligned (I tried using the `center` environment, but it didn't work).

I guess centre aligned designation below the signature line would be great.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
User Representative & Date\\[8ex]% adds space between the two sets of signatures
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
Program Manager & Date\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possibilities to do what you want.  Because I'm not
sure if centering is always the best I will show you two other
possibilities for the layout.  One is using the usual block (please see the hyphenation!), one is to use `\raggedright`, that means left justified text and all centered.

The code (with your used class `memoir`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.5in}p{2.5in}@{}}
\dotfill                         & \dotfill\\
Dr. Fernando Torres              & Date\\
(Assistant Professor Discipline Of Computer Science School Of Engineering La Liga)  
                                 & \\[8ex]
\dotfill                         & \dotfill\\
Dr. Fernando Torres              & Date\\
\raggedright (Assistant Professor Discipline Of Computer Science School Of Engineering La Liga)  
                                 & \\[8ex]
\end{tabular} 

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{2.5in}>{\centering}p{2.5in}@{}}
\dotfill                         & \dotfill \tabularnewline
Dr. Fernando Torres              &  Date \tabularnewline
(Assistant Professor Discipline Of Computer Science School Of Engineering La Liga)  
                                 &  \tabularnewline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Screenshot of compiled mwe]

Please see that I used `\tabularnewline` for the last table because
the different layout with `\centering`). To get a centered column I used `>{\centering}` before `p{2.5in}`, because `p{2.5in}` will create a right-left justified column and you need a centered one.

Answer (score 5):

The following should provide you with what you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.5in}p{2.5in}@{}}
  \dotfill & \dotfill \\
  Some name & Date \\[5\bigskipamount]
  \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\
  Some other name & Date \\
  \centering
  Some lengthy designation that makes the above-mentioned person feel 
  special to everyone who reads this
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The key here is to use a `p{<len>}` style column, as it allows you to perform regular paragraph-like settings (horizontal alignment), including `\centering` to centre the content.